# JavaScript function to split the string and return the combination in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function to split a string by its delimiter ('/') and wanted to return its path combination in an array.

Input:

**"Global/Europe/UK/London"**

Desired Output:

**["Global","Global/Europe","Global/Europe/UK"]**

I tried the below recursive function, but for some reason the array contains only a single value.

```
function splitPath(str) {
    var output = [];
    if (str.lastIndexOf('/') !== -1) {        
        str = str.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
        output.push(str);
        splitPath(str);
    }
    //console.log(output);
    return output;
}
```

Please let me know if there's any straight way to achieve this in JavaScript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let input = "Global/Europe/UK/London";
let output = input.split("/").slice(0, -1).reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    acc.push(index ? acc[index - 1] + '/' + item : item);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could split the string and map with the parts from the beginning by using only the parts without the last one.

```js
var string = "Global/Europe/UK/London",
    grouped = string
        .split('/')
        .slice(0, -1)
        .map(function (_, i, a) {
            return a.slice(0, i + 1).join('/');
        });

console.log(grouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to split and then iteratively add the parts:

```js
    function splitPath(str) {
       const parts = str.split("/");
       let head = parts.shift();
       const result = [head];
       for (const part of parts) {
          head += "/" + part;
          result.push(head);
       }
    
      return result;
    }
    
    console.log(splitPath("Global/Europe/UK/London"))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
   let output = [];
    let input = str.split('/');
    input.reduce((acc,v, i, arr) => {  output.push(acc + "/"+ v ); return acc + "/"+ v; })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'Global/Europe/UK/London'
    .split('/')
    .map(
        (item, i, items) => {
            return items.slice(0, i+1).join('/');
        }
    )
```